# Parse Input from GUI instead of Console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have a small GUI project with a text-box and submit button. What I want to do is for user to type into the text-box and submit an input that would move them through the program (ex. 1 to go to next menu). The program did not use to have a GUI and used console to enter input (as seen in the first code) and so I want to move the program away from console.

Right now my main is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    //Initialize menu variable
    Menu menu = MainMenu.getInstance();

    new Console();
    while (true){
        //Display current menu
        menu.displayMenu();
        while (menu.moreInputNeeded()){
            menu.displayPrompt();
            try {
                // Process user input.
                menu.parseInput(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println(Prompt.INVALID_INPUT);
            }
        }

        menu = menu.getNextMenu();
    }
}
```

and I use a text/submit button as followed:

```
        //Create the Text Box
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

    //Submit Button
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");


    //Submit Function
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            menuinput = textField.getText();
            textField.setText("");

            //
            System.out.println(menuinput);

        }
    });
```

So is it possible to process user input from the GUI instead of the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own question. I implemented:

```
    //Variables
JTextField tfIn;
JLabel lblOut;
private final PipedInputStream inPipe = new PipedInputStream();
private final PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream();
PrintWriter inWriter;

String input = null;
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
//Variables

    System.setIn(inPipe); 
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true)); 
        inWriter = new PrintWriter(new PipedOutputStream(inPipe), true); 
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        return;
    }
    tfIn = new JTextField();
    tfIn.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(tfIn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

With Method:

```
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    textArea.setText("");
    String text = tfIn.getText();
    tfIn.setText("");
    inWriter.println(text); 
}
```

There might be some other little aspects I missed but that's the most important parts.